# Truffle test msg.value is zero when sending ether to contract

Tags: truffle

I really feel like am missing something very basic but I cannot figure out why my truffle test fails when sending ether to a contract function. My test code is as follows:

```
it('Test execute funds deposit', async function () {
    await fundsDepositServiceInstance.depositEther(
        accountAddr, accountNo, {from:accounts[0], value: 100, gas: 4712388});
});
```

My solidity code is as follows:

```
function depositEther(address _accountAddr, bytes32 _accountNo) external payable {
    require(msg.value < 1, "Insufficient funds to complete transaction");
}
```

Running Truffle v4.1.14, Ganache v1.2.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
The revert code is always activated and my test fails. My apologies if this is some basic error on my side. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `require` statement is requiring `msg.value < 1` yet you are calling `depositEther` with a `value` of 100. Therefore your code is doing what is expected and your test should fail.